# rsync between Ubuntu and FreeBSD

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rsync, freebsd

I am trying to rsync files between my home Ubuntu 14.04 i686 server (which is backup storage) and jailed FreeBSD 10.3-PRERELEASE #5 amd64 (which is web server).

I use following command (real IP is another for sure):

```
rsync -uvrhtl --delete-after -e="ssh -l user -p 2222" 8.8.8.8:/hosting/my.site /backup/my.site
```

And I get following error:

```
Password for user@example.com:
receiving file list ... Connection to 8.8.8.8 closed by remote host.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (16384 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

At the same time scp works fine:

```
$ scp -P 2222 user@8.8.8.8:/hosting/my.site/index.php /backup/my.site/
Password for user@example.com:
index.php
$ ls /backup/my.site/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 418 Jan 25 17:00 /backup/my.site/index.php
```

If I try to make the same on FreeBSD I get following

```
rsync -uvrhtl user@home.com:/backup/my.site ~/tmp/
user@home.com's password: 
receiving incremental file list
created directory /home/user/tmp
./
site-folders-and-files/
...
...
...
site-folders-and-files/folders/folders/README
Write failed: Permission denied
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (58914 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (67040 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [generator=3.1.1]
```

rsync versions are following. FreeBSD:

```
user@freebsd % rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2014 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 32-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, no iconv, symtimes, no prealloc, file-flags

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

And Ubuntu:

```
user@ubuntu$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2014 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 32-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: just an idea froma guy who doesn't really know rsync. FreeBSD has additional user rights on files, which are called 'flags'. This may cause your issues. What I'd do would've been to try to sync with same host (e.g. FreeBSD <-> FreeBSD on QEMU), and then would continue to see what's up with the FreeBSD -> Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The reason was in FreeBSD jail configuration. What was done to resolved the problem:

- on the host FreeBSD machine: in `/etc/sysctl.conf` set
  `net.inet.tcp.tso=0`
- in jail: in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add `UsePAM yes`
- and then update everything in jail to be the same version as on the host FreeBSD